# Encoding/Decoding videos in Android

Tags: java, android, video

I am currently creating a video maker app and it features export to various video formats, specifically to MP4, AVI, and MPEG. But I don't know how to encode/decode videos from the images drawn by the user. I know FFMPEG, but I don't know where to find it.
The main problem here is I just don't know how to encode videos from an array of images. Maybe you could include code snippets on how to encode/decode audio file formats and merged it with the video.

Comment: What software you use? Eclipse/ android studio?

Comment: In order to do so, you should import the library "ffmpeg4android_lib" into your project so you can use FFMPEG functions.  you can look at this example: http://androidwarzone.blogspot.co.il/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html